# Add "ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)" as attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I create a Mail from a Template and add some attributes from the highlighted Mail.

I would like the original marked E-Mail (`ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)`) as attachment to the replyEmail.

My code so far:

```vb
Dim replyEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim actualEmail As Outlook.MailItem
 
Set actualEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("U:\Template.oft")
    
replyEmail.To = actualEmail.To
replyEmail.CC = actualEmail.CC

' Here comes the tricky part, where i would like the original marked E-Mail (ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)) as attachment to the replyEmail!

replyEmail.attachment = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
replyEmail.Display
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy:

```
replyEmail.Attachments.Add actualEmail
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly i always get an Runtime Error 438 when i debug to this line.

Comment: Try to remove ()

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!